# QT click on button in widget without focus

Tags: qt, click, focus

i have an app where i have 2 widgets, one widget shows a video and the other one two buttons as transparent widget lying over the video. Means the widget with the buttons has the focus. When now somebody clicks on the video normally this should emit a signal to open a website in an external browser, but while the other widget has the focus, this signal is not emitted while the click only changes the focus to the video but is not getting the click itself.

is there a way to use the click, to change the focus and catch the click event to open my website?

Georg

Comment: Maybe you can just use the click event of the video widget itself and split it into two areas (like 2 buttons you have now)?

Comment: Something wrong with your buttons. Normally, when you have multiple buttons you can press each of them regardless of the focus (if you click with mouse) and you don't need to perform two clicks - one for bringing in focus and second to click it. I guess, in your case first click gets caught by some other widget, not by the button itself.

Comment: @FloatFlower, what you wrote about each widget has its own event loop - is not true.

Comment: the button si can click individually, the problem is when i click on the video what is in a widget behind the one where the buttons are in, it takes 2 clicks to get the clickevent on it to trigger the website (1st for the focus, 2nd for the clickhandler)

Comment: Provide a [mcve] and you increase your chance of getting specific help instead of guesses.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you can try the function: setFocusProxy()

```
video.setFocusProxy(button);
```

Maybe you can get some help.